# Bootstrap Dropdown Not Styling Properly in rtl mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why does this happen to my bootsrap dropdown ?

[image]

Comment: provide the minimal code required to reproduce the problem, please.

Comment: can you suplly a link to your site?